# Can I use the idiom "every time" this way?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

Every time is defined as *whenever there is a choice* by OALD. However, before I read this definition, I have different view about its definition and I always thought that "every time" is similar to "everyday" but happens more often.

Anyway, can I use the phrase this way in this context below:

> How often do I feel anxious? **Every time**!

If *every time* doesn't work in that context, what is the most possible phrase or word?

Comment: "Every time" sounds weird here, but "all the time" would be perfectly natural.

Comment: @KefSchecter: "Every time" could be fine, depending on the context: "I go on stage and perform every day. How often do I feel anxious? Every time!". The key, as pointed out in SegNerd's answer, is that the context has to supply (implicitly or explicitly) something that has already happened several times.

Comment: Example of explicitly provided context: "Every time I go on stage and perform!" It's effectively short for "Every time I go on stage and perform, I feel anxious!"

Comment: "Every" is usually used in reference to countable objects. Continuous time is not countable.

Comment: Sounds like the punchline of a joke, a la Airplane!'s "No, I've been nervous before."

Comment: I think "every time" is OK when you add "...when ...". In contrast "every day" somehow implies "once per day". So maybe be more specific.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It only works if you are speaking in the context of a finite event that has happened several times. For example, you could say:

“I’ve been on 8 first dates this year. How often do I feel anxious? Every time!”

If you just say “How often do I feel anxious? Every time!” without any context, it doesn’t make sense. If you are just speaking generally without reference to a specific thing that happened, it would be better to say “All the time.”

Comment: Not necessarily a finite event that _has happened_ several times, but one that at least _can be imagined to have the possibility of happening_ several times. The event(s) can be hypothetical or in the future – the main thing is that it makes sense to talk about something occurring on every occasion that the event is/was/will be/would be repeated.

Answer (score 10):

The question should be "How often **do** I feel anxious?" and the answer you provide, "Every time!" makes us ask, "Every time *what?*". Something is missing, e.g. "Every time a big nasty dog barks at me". If you mean to express that you feel anxious "all the time", the question would be "**When** do you feel anxious?". "How often?" asks for the number of times.

Comment: I agree with the first part of this answer. But colloquially, I don't think "how often" has to refer to countable events. "All the time" would be a reasonable answer to "How often do I feel anxious?"

Answer (score 3):

It's been implied in other answers, but not stated explicitly, that  "every time" and "all the time" use two different meanings of the word "time". As Barmar said in a comment, the former is countable (like beans) and the latter is uncountable (like water).

The construction "every X" forces us to interpret X as countable. Specifically, "every time" uses meaning
3.4 below (abridged from the ["time" wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=time&oldid=65600074), with emphasis added) whereas "all the time" uses meaning 1 (or possibly a version of 2).

> *time* (countable and uncountable, plural *times*)
>
> 1. **(uncountable) The inevitable progression into the future with the passing of present and past events.**
>
>    - ***Time** stops for nobody.*
>    - *the ebb and flow of **time***
> 2. A duration of time.
> 3. An instant of time.
>
>    3.1. (uncountable) How much of a day has passed; the moment, as indicated by a clock or similar device.
>
>    3.2. (countable) A particular moment or hour; the appropriate moment or hour for something (especially with prepositional phrase or imperfect subjunctive).
>
>    3.3. (countable) A numerical indication of a particular moment.
>
>    3.4. **(countable) An instance or occurrence:**
>
>    - *When was the last **time** we went out? I don’t remember.*
>    - *see you another **time***
>    - *that’s three **times** he’s made the same mistake*
>    - *Okay, but this is the last **time**. No more after that!*
>
>    3.5 (UK, in public houses) Closing time.
>
>    3.6 The hour of childbirth.
>
>    3.7 (as *someone's time*) The end of someone's life, conceived by the speaker as having been predestined.
> 4. (countable) The measurement under some system of region of day or moment.
> 5. (countable) Ratio of comparison.
> 6. (grammar, dated) Tense.
> 7. (music) The measured duration of sounds; measure; tempo; rate of movement; rhythmical division.

It's probably worth mentioning that you *can* use "every X" to get the sense of "all the time" if you divide time into countable units. A person who has (and is hopefully seeking help for) Generalized Anxiety Disorder might say:

- *How often do I feel anxious?  **Every second** of the day!*
- *How often do I feel anxious?  **Every** waking **moment**!*

If you want to keep the word "time", you need a construction that does not force a countable interpretation, such as:

- *How often do I feel anxious?  **All the time**!*